# Consulta sobre la palabra reservada "super()" JAVA

Tags: java, poo, herencia, clase-abstracta

Buenas tardes, en mi proyecto tengo los siguientes atributos y constructor de una Clase Abstracta:

```
//Attributes
private int number;

//Constructor
public Card ( int number ) {

    this.number = number ;
}
```

De la cual hereda la siguiente Clase :

```
public abstract class SpainCard extends Card {

//Attributes
private int number ;
private String suit ;

//Constructor
public SpainCard(int number, String suit) {

    super(number);
    this.suit = suit;

}
```

Mi consulta es la siguiente, que genera la palabra reservada `super(number);` en el constructor de mi `Abstract class SpainCard` ?
Estoy heredando el atriburo `int number` de mi `class` padre, o que hace internamente JAVA al utilizar `super();` ?.

Es una consulta para que pueda entender de mejor manera como funciona y se utiliza de buena manera `super();` ya que mi código funciona como esta, pero tengo dudas de que hace exactamente.

Muchas gracias, espero que puedan explicarme con mayor detalle.

Comment: Ese `super(number)` vendría a ser el constructor de la clase extendida `Card`

Comment: @Jorius , no comprendi lo que me quisiste decir. Te referís a que estoy llamando al constructor de la Clase `Card` ?..
Eso no seria haciendo `super()."nombre_del_constructor"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que la documentación de Java lo explica bastante claro, el problema es que está en inglés.

Me permito dejarla aquí traducida, de forma que ayude a la comprensión de futuros programadores, ya que se trata de una pregunta interesante, sobre todo cuando empezamos a programar en Java.

## Uso de la palabra clave super

### Acceso a miembros de Superclase

Si su método reemplaza uno de los métodos de su superclase, puede invocar el método sobreescrito (override) mediante el uso de la palabra clave `super`. También puede utilizar `super` para referirse a un campo oculto (aunque se desaconseja ocultar campos).

Considere esta clase, `Superclase`:

```
public class Superclass {

    public void printMethod() {
        System.out.println("Printed in Superclass.");
    }
}
```

Aquí está una subclase, llamada `Subclase`, que reemplaza (sobreescribe) a `printMethod ()`:

Here is a subclass, called Subclass, that overrides printMethod():

```
public class Subclass extends Superclass {

    // sobreescribe printMethod en Superclass
    public void printMethod() {
        super.printMethod();
        System.out.println("Printed in Subclass");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Subclass s = new Subclass();
        s.printMethod();    
    }
}
```

Dentro de la Subclase, el nombre simple `printMethod()` se refiere al declarada en Subclase, que reemplaza al de Superclase. Por lo tanto, para referirse a `printMethod()` heredado de `Superclase`, `Subclase` debe utilizar un nombre calificado, usando `super` como se muestra. Cuando compilamos y ejecutamos a `Subclase` imprime lo siguiente:

```
Printed in Superclass.
Printed in Subclass.
```

### Constructores de subclases

El siguiente ejemplo ilustra cómo utilizar la palabra clave `super` para invocar al constructor de una superclase. Recordemos del ejemplo [`Bicycle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) que `MountainBike` es una subclase de `Bicycle`. Aquí está el constructor `MountainBike` (subclase) que llama al constructor de la superclase y luego agrega un código de inicialización propio:

```
public MountainBike(int startHeight, 

                        int startCadence,
                        int startSpeed,
                        int startGear) {
        super(startCadence, startSpeed, startGear);
        seatHeight = startHeight;
    }
```

La invocación de un constructor de superclase debe ser la primera línea en el constructor de la subclase.

La sintaxis para llamar a un constructor de superclase es

```
super();
```

o:

```
super (lista de parámetros);
```

Con `super()`, se llama al constructor sin argumentos de la superclase. Con `super (lista de parámetros)`, se llama al constructor de superclase con una lista de parámetros correspondiente.

> Nota: Si un constructor no invoca explícitamente un constructor de
>   superclase, el compilador Java inserta automáticamente una llamada al
>   constructor sin argumentos de la superclase. Si la superclase no tiene
>   un constructor sin argumento, obtendrá un error en tiempo de
>   compilación. El objeto tiene tal constructor, así que si el objeto es
>   la única superclase, no hay problema.

Si un constructor de subclase invoca un constructor de su superclase, explícita o implícitamente, puede imaginar que habrá una cadena completa de constructores llamados, todo el camino de regreso al constructor de Object. De hecho, este es el caso. Se le llama *encadenamiento de constructor*, y es necesario estar consciente de ello cuando hay una larga línea de descenso de clase.

---

- Fuente: [Documentación de Java: Using the Keyword super](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

Comment: Excelente, me resulto verdaderamente util, ahora entiendo un poco mejor.. Muchas gracias por la ayuda..

Answer (score 7):

Es fácil probarlo:

```
public class SpainCard extends Card {

    //Attributes
    private int number;
    private String suit;

    //Constructor
    public SpainCard(int number, String suit) {

        super(number);
        this.suit = suit;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpainCard c = new SpainCard(1, "");
        System.out.println("number " + c.number);
    }
}
```

imprime `0`. Es decir que el constructor del padre (`Card`) usó su propio atributo. Lo cual es lógico. El atributo `number` del hijo no fue asignado.

> que hace internamente JAVA al utilizar `super();`?

Simplemente llama al constructor del padre - con esos argumentos. Ahora bien, el constructor del padre, cuando fue compilado, "sabía" que en la sentencia `this.number = number ;` el atributo que está a la izquierda es "su" atributo. No cambia nada que al ejecutarse este constructor se esté construyendo en realidad un objeto de la clase hija, con su propio atributo con el mismo nombre. 
El atributo (field) concreto que se usa queda fijado en tiempo de compilación. No hay algo así como un ["override" de atributos en Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086298/why-instance-variable-of-super-class-is-not-overridden-in-sub-class-method), solo de métodos.

Espero que te quede claro que esto de usar un mismo atributo privado en dos clases (uno que extiende a otra) no es en sí un error, pero no es nada aconsejable.

Para aclarar más:

```
public class Card {
    private int number = -1;

    public Card ( int number ) {
         System.out.println("Entrando a constructor de Card: number era " + this.number);
         this.number = number ;
         System.out.println("Saliendo de constructor de Card;  number es " + this.number);
    }
}

public class SpainCard extends Card {

    private int number = -2;
    private String suit;

    public SpainCard(int number, String suit) {
        super(number);
        this.suit = suit;
        System.out.println("Saliendo de constructor de SpainCard; mi number es " + this.number);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpainCard c = new SpainCard(10, "");
        System.out.println("number " + c.number);
    }
}
```

Deberías poder predecir (pregunta de examen!) lo que esto imprime.

> `Entrando a constructor de Card; number era -1 
>  Saliendo de constructor de Card; number es 10 
>  Saliendo de constructor de SpainCard;  mi number es -2 
>  number -2`

Comment: Entonces lo que haría en este caso `super();` seria llamar al atributo `number` de su clase padre, no ?..
Si me imagino que no es conveniente poner los nombres de los atributos similares o precisamente iguales. Solamente es la consigna asi el Ejercicio que me toco, ademas despues `SpainCard` también es `abstract` y cada palo de las cartas españolas heredan de esta.

Muchas gracias por la respuesta! .

Comment: Si. No solo el constructor, sino cualquier metod de SpainCard, al referenciar al atributo `number` referenciará siempre a su propio atributo, sin importar que el objeto en realidad sea un descendiente SpainCard de que tal vez tenga otro atributo con ese nombre.

Answer (score 1):

Tu codigo en este fragmento :

```
//Constructor
public SpainCard(int number, String suit) {

    super(number);//llamada al constructor de la Clase Padre (Card) ya que hereda de ella y le envia el parametro number , el cual tiene definido el constructor de Card
    this.suit = suit;

}
```

En Java al crear una instancia de la Clase se llama al constructor , y el constructor en su primera linea llama al constructor de la clase padre con super();

veamos unos ejemplos

```
public class Clase1
{
    public Clase1()
    {
        //el compilador añade la llamada a super() ya que esta no fue añadida por el programador en este caso llama a Object
        System.out.println("constructor Clase1");
    }

    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Clase3 clase3 = new Clase3();
    }

}

class Clase2 extends Clase1
{
    public Clase2()
    {
        //el compilador añade la llamada a super() ya que esta no fue añadida por el programador en este caso llama a Clase1
        System.out.println("constructor Clase2");
    }
}

class Clase3 extends Clase2
{
    public Clase3()
    {
        //el compilador añade la llamada a super() ya que esta no fue añadida por el programador en este caso llama a Clase2
        System.out.println("constructor Clase3");
    }
}
```

Comment: Tengo otra duda, donde se almacenaría el parámetro `number` que le envía la Clase padre  ?


Si hiciera esto en constructor de la clase `SpainCard`


   `super(number);`


   `this.number=number;`


Utilizaria `number`de mi Padre o `number`de `SpainCard`


Muchas gracias por responder.

Comment: @MatiasSimone  `this.number` (en el constructor o en cualquier método) siempre referenciará el atributo `number` de la clase en la cual está declarado ese constructor o método (o de una clase padre si no se encuentra en esa clase). Lo importante es advertir que la referencia concreta de `this.atributoX`  siempre se resuelve en tiempo de compilación, mientras que `this.metodoX()` (salvo que `metodoX()` sea `final`) se resuelve en tiempo de ejecución (y por lo tanto puede llegar a corresponder a método de un hijo; no podemos saberlo en tiempo de compilación).